# What is trivializing open cover?

Tags: differential-geometry

Here is where I read "trivializing open cover", but I was not able to find out what it is.

[image]

Comment: I believe a trivializing open cover is an open cover of M by such neighborhoods U as in the first paragraph.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's just as Dylan Yott says in his comment.  A fiber bundle is by definition locally trivial: around every point there is a neighborhood where the bundle is isomorphic [in whatever category; here, differentiably] to a "trivial bundle", i.e., just taking the product of the base with the fiber.  So to define the bundle using **transition functions** as is being done here, one needs to cover the base by open neighborhoods $U_i$ such that the bundle is trivial -- i.e., isomorphic to a product -- on each $U_i$.  That's a trivializing open cover.